# How could a Phone Lose Sim service just by an ADB command No Root

Tags: imei

This is sort of a debugging/learning post. I followed this post [By Schematic here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208885/can-i-change-which-sim-a-phone-is-using-for-its-lte-interface-using-adb?answertab=active#tab-top) on a Qualcomm device.

After typing this command `adb shell service call phone 180 i32 1 i32 0`,
The Phone lost both its Networks and IMEI reports null, Baseband is unknown.

How could an ADB Shell without root cause such a damage? OEM unlocking was OFF.

Comment: Hello. Did you restart the device? Service calls varies Android version-wise, so which Android version and device are you using?

Comment: Yes I did restart the device and also Factory reset through settings. I am using Oppo Realme XT RMX1921 on Android 9

Comment: I think you need to **manually reload your IMEI numbers**. It mostly occurs in Mediatek devices, but since it is a Qualcomm device, the process is a bit complex but you can follow this guide: https://cellphonetrackers.org/change-imei-number-snapdragon-device.html

Comment: This tool requires me to unlock my phone's bootloader and that would void my phone's warranty.

Comment: I finally took the device to service center. And the executive said he would send the case to Realme and he is not certain that it would be covered under warranty as the imei is broken. But my device's bootloader is untouched and I never tried rooting.